# PLSQL IS TABLE OF returns 0

Tags: arrays, plsql

I am trying to add my data from table to plsql-array => table. 
My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "MY_DATABASE"."EMPLOYEES" 
   (    "EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) CONSTRAINT "EMP_LAST_NAME_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) CONSTRAINT "EMP_EMAIL_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE, )
```

Now I am trying to save data into type "is table", but no data will be selected
and i don't entry my loop.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
declare

  TYPE employees_table_typ IS TABLE OF employees%ROWTYPE
          INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  employees_table employees_table_typ;

  v_index BINARY_INTEGER;

begin
    dbms_output.put_line('COUNT: '||employees_table.count);
  v_index := employees_table.first;
     dbms_output.put_line('BEFORE Loop ');
  while v_index is not NULL loop


    dbms_output.put_line('FIRST_NAME: '|| employees_table(v_index).FIRST_NAME);
    dbms_output.put_line('INDEX: ' || v_index);
    v_index := employees_table.next (v_index);

  end loop;

     dbms_output.put_line('AFTER Loop ');
end;
```

Whats could be wrong here? When i count my records, i get 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared a variable, nut you never put anything into it, so it's empty when you check the number of records.

If you want to use a variable to host some values, you have to populate it; for example, this

```
DECLARE
    TYPE employees_table_typ IS TABLE OF employees%ROWTYPE
        INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    employees_table                         employees_table_typ;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('BEFORE - COUNT: ' || employees_table.COUNT);
    --
    select *
    bulk collect into employees_table
    from employees;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('AFTER - COUNT: ' || employees_table.COUNT);    
END;
```

gives

```
BEFORE - COUNT: 0
AFTER - COUNT: 2
```

Same thing for a scalar variable:

```
declare
    v   varchar2(10);
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('before - v: ' || v);
    --
    select 'some value'
    into v
    from dual;    
    dbms_output.put_line('after - v: ' || v);
end;
```

gives:

```
before - v:
after - v: some value
```

Comment: Thx you. It works!! I just forgot to select. But when i would do that, it would still not working, because i "bulk collect".
When i should you it? I thought, i just have to select all data.

Comment: It's not that clear to me. Please edit the question to post what you've done and the error you're getting

Comment: Within my script, i just forgot to select data. But when i would not forget this, i did not still use "bulk collect"-expression. I would use only "select * from table*
When i should use this expression "bulk collect"?

Comment: A select without an INTO makes no sense in a PLSQL block. You need to use an INTO, for a single value, or a BULK COLLECT INTO if your query returns more than one row.